# How to Implement Async logging in log4cplus

Tags: c++, log4cplus

I want to implement `AsyncAppender` in log4cplus to write the event asynchronously into the file. Please guide me with any sample code.

Comment: What version of log4cplus do you use?

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using log4cplus master branch but one of the released versions then you should be able to use this configuration to wrap, e.g., `FileAppender` with `AsyncAppender`:

```
log4cplus.appender.TEST=log4cplus::AsyncAppender
log4cplus.appender.TEST.Appender=log4cplus::FileAppender
log4cplus.appender.TEST.Appender.File=test_output.log
log4cplus.appender.TEST.Appender.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout
log4cplus.appender.TEST.Appender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%q} [%t] %-5p %c <%x> - %m%n
```

If you are using master branch of log4cplus Git repository then all you need to do is to set `AsyncAppend` property of your appender to `true` and the magic will happen.